# Expand variable in list in LISP

Tags: variables, lisp

I wanted the following code to work. How do I make one-level variables expand?

```
(let* ((data1 10)
       (data2 '(data1 20)))
  (progn data2))
```

I expected `(10 20)` but in the fact I got `(data1 20)`. Also I'd like to get `(10 20 (data2))` from the following:

```
 (let* ((data1 10)
        (data2 30)
        (data3 '(data 10 20 '(data2)))
   (progn data3))
```

Comment: If you want to learn the basics of Lisp, I'd recommend this book: [Common Lisp: A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/). A PDF-Version can be downloaded there.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that the variable does not expand is that you quoted the whole list using `'`. `'` is not how you create lists in lisp, it's how you quote them (i.e. cause them not to be evaluated).

To create a list containing the contents of `data1` and the number 20, just use `(list data1 20)`.

Answer (score 1):

As sepp2k said, the usual way to create lists at runtime is the `list` function. Quoted lists are list literals, of literal values.

But there's another way to create lists at runtime that looks more similar to quoted lists, the backquote. You could achieve what you want with

```
`(,data1 20)
```

Another thing regarding your examples: You don't need the `progn`s there. `progn` is for sequencing multiple expressions and then return the value of the last of them, if it's just a single value expression, you can just use itself without the wrapping. But even if you had multiple expressions, you wouldn't need to use `progn` in this case, because `let*` implicitly puts a `progn` around the body.